# How to prevent buffer overflow by giving same array of value to variables?

Tags: c, sizeof, buffer-overflow

I am confused regarding Buffer Overflow. I have a code in which I declared variables with a different array of values. *Like*

```
char name[20], address[30], account[15];
int id[10], dob[10], accountType[20];
```

But then I used **STRING_LEN 50** which I gave to every variable *like*

```
char name[STRING_LEN], address[STRING_LEN], account[STRING_LEN];
int id[STRING_LEN], dob[STRING_LEN], accountType[STRING_LEN];
```

So instead of using **scanf** I used **fgets**. My question is that will it prevent buffer overflow even if I wrote **STRING_LEN** or **sizeof** and they will manage it OR will I have to give a different array of values to every variable?

Comment: I know but my question is, will it prevent buffer overflow because the limitation of the word is high but actual length is b/w 10-30. What is the working of sizeof in this case?

Comment: Even if the length of STRING_LEN is high?

Comment: so should I write `STRING_LEN - 1` in fgets or just `STRING_LEN`?

Comment: Here is reference documentation for *fgets*: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Answer (score 2):

With a declaration like `char name[20];` you use the fgets function like this:

```
const char *p = fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
if (p != NULL) {
    /*proceed*/
} else {
    /*handle end of file*/
}
```

Replace *stdin* if you want to read from a different file. In this case fgets reads up to 19 characts and (if the reading was successful) terminates *name* with the character '\0'.

See also the reference documentation at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/

Comment: I have a question about buffer over that will STRING_LEN will remove it or not even if name has 20 characters limit and STRING_LEN has 50. Will it prevent buffer overflow? and sizeof does in this case?

Comment: @BilalKhan In this case buffer overflow only occurs if fgets tries to assign characters beyond the end of the array that you supply. This can only happen if the second parameter is larger than the size of the array; for instance, this would be wrong: `fgets(name, 21, stdin)`. With `fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin)` the function will only read at most 19 characters.